# Romans 6:7 Was Christ Set Free From Sin?

Tags: greek, romans, christology, context, sin

**Ignoring one's own particular theology and overall integrated understanding of the Bible, for a moment, is it good Greek to translate Romans 6:7 as something like the following?**

> **"for he having died** has been set free from sin."

or

> "**for the one having died** has been set free from sin."

Most translations seem to reflect something similar to the ESV where:

> **For one who has died** has been set free from sin.

The predominant flavor of translations seem to indicate that any particular person who has died has been set free from The Sin. However it seems to me most natural that,

> ὁ γὰρ ἀποθανὼν δεδικαίωται ἀπὸ τῆς ἁμαρτίας,

is talking about a particular person who has died who has been set free from sin - that person, in context, necessarily being Christ.

I imagine that my translation/interpretation would usually be ruled out based on a general understanding of Christ's relationship to sin, however, I'd like to ignore that for the sake of this question and consider only the translation with respect to the immediate context.

**Please consider my bolded translation within the context of Romans 6:4-11 based on the ESV translation.**

> 4 We were buried therefore with him by baptism into death, in order that, just as Christ was raised from the dead by the glory of the Father, we too might walk in newness of life. 5 For if we have been united with him in a death like his, we shall certainly be united with him in a resurrection like his. 6 We know that our old self [humanity] was crucified with him in order that the body of sin might be brought to nothing, so that we would no longer be enslaved to sin. 7 **For he, having died, has been set free from sin.** 8 Now if we have died with Christ, we believe that we will also live with him. 9 We know that Christ, being raised from the dead, will never die again; death no longer has dominion over him. 10 *For the death he died he died to sin, once for all, but the life he lives he lives to God. 11 So you also must consider yourselves dead to sin and alive to God in Christ Jesus.* (Romans 6:4-11)

---

**Note:**
*To answer this question I'm asking you to ignore the larger Biblical teaching on Sin and Christ and focus on the Greek of verse 7 and the immediately surrounding context.* The reason why I think it's valuable to ignore the larger context of what we understand the Bible to be saying is because sometimes a faithful reading of a particular verse may require us to reevaluate what we understand the Bible to say in other places. If we always interpret what we read by what we already understand we may miss out on some deeper truth.

Comment: The question seems fine to me, but it's far too long. Don't include your own answer and justification in the question. You can write an answer instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems angled to be so restricted in what hermeneutic points are acceptable to the PO, that only hermeneutic points that agree with the angle of the question will be accepted.

Comment: He was made sin for us 2 Cor 5:21. And then, in death, sin was no more. So, yes, he was set free from sin (as were all for whom he died). This is a very clear concept in scripture. Christ was made sin on behalf of others and death ended that sin, making He, as Head, and all under his headship free from sin. This is a fundamental facet of the gospel. But I cannot see the necessity of asking such an obvious question/answer on a site such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

Romans 6:6-7, "Knowing this, that our old "man/old self" was crucified with Him, that are body of sin might be done away with, that we should no longer be slaves to sin."

"Old man" refers to our former self, the unregenerate son of Adam. We were put to death with Christ. The emphasis is on the conclusion or results of an action. We have been buried, we have become united. The person we once were is now dead.

While the "old man" is ourselves in union with the first Adam, the "new man" is ourselves in union with the last Adam. God says that my old life was destroyed, put to death, at Calvary. God's Word is the basis of fact. Our first step is "knowing."

The term "destroyed" does not mean annihilated but rendered "powerless." Sin is not destroyed, but is robbed of its power. The one who is born again is commanded to take his stand on this verse for "he that is dead is freed from sin." Death breaks all ties and cancels all obligations.

By his union with Christ the Christian dies to the old self and is free from it, even as the Law has no jurisdiction over a dead man, regardless of his crime. The only power that cause the believer to sin now is his own power of choice. He can sin, but he does not have to do so.

1 John 2:1 states, "My little children, I am writing these things to you that you may not sin. And if anyone sins, we have an Advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous. And 1 John 3:9, "No one who is born of God PRACTICES sin, because His seed abides in him; and he cannot sin, because he is born of God."

Comment: Not my dv btw. 1/ it doesn't answer the Q re Christ and sin so prob. deserves a dv. 2/ Do you not see the paradox within your explanation re 'born again'? "he cannot sin"? This is why traditional doctrine has lost the plot. "he *cannot* sin BECAUSE he is born of God." 'Cannot' overrides 'practises'. Before you go off on a rant about something else, (which you are prone to do) let's stick with this 'cannot' bit within the realms of 'born from above'.

Comment: @steveowen You said, "he cannot sin BECAUSE he is born of God." You have this "butt" backwards like the rest of your errant theology. 1 John 3:5, "You know that he appeared to take away sins, and in him there was no sin." 1 Peter 2:22, "He committed no sin, neither was deceit found in his mouth." And how about John 3:3 where Jesus says, "Jesus answered him, "Truly, truly, I say to you, unless one is born again (like me) he cannot see the kingdom of God." John 8:46, "Which one of you convicts me of sin? If I tell the truth, why do you not believe me? (after all I was born again like you).

Answer (score 0):

There are several matters here.

**1. Meaning of the verb δικαιόω (dikaioó)**

It is true that most of the time, dikaioó means acquit or vindicate.  However, according to BDAG, one of its shades of meaning is:

> **3. to cause someone to be released from personal or institutional claims that are no longer pertinent or valid, *make free/pure***, eg,
> Acts 13:38, 39, Rom 6:7, 1 Cor 6:11, 1 Tim 3:16.

Thus, the translation, "has been freed" is perfectly acceptable.

**2. Translation of Rom 6:7**

I agree with the BLB which renders Rom 6:7 as:

> For the *one* having died has been freed from sin.

**3. Context**

In the flow of Paul's argument, Rom 6:7 is a parenthetical remark to support his overall thesis that death releases from sin.  That is, a dead person cannot sin because such a person cannot do anything, and, such a person cannot be tempted and is thus released from the power of sin.

This is in contrast to Jesus' death which Paul is at pains to show is a vicarious death - He died for us so that we do not need to die eternally.  See appendix below.

The point of Paul's arguement is stated several times in Rom 6

- V6 - For if we have been united with Him like this in His death, we will certainly also be united with Him in His resurrection.
- V8 - Now if we died with Christ, we believe that we will also live with Him.
- V10 - The death He died, He died to sin once for all; but the life He lives, He lives to God.

Back to Rom 6:7 - Paul simply says in here that either we are freed from sin by own own eternal death (Rom 6:23) or we are freed from sin by accepting Christ's death on our behalf and are thus freed from sin.

Ellicott says this -

> (7) Is freed.—“Absolved,” the same word that is used elsewhere for
> “justified.” The dead man is no longer liable to have the charge of
> sin brought against him. This is the general proposition, the major
> premise, adduced in proof of what had gone before, viz., the
> particular proposition that he who is ethically dead is no longer the
> slave of sin.

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary is more detailed:

> 7. For he that is dead—rather, "hath died." is freed—"hath been set free."  from sin—literally, "justified," "acquitted," "got his
>    discharge from sin." As death dissolves all claims, so the whole claim
>    of sin, not only to "reign unto death," but to keep its victims in
>    sinful bondage, has been discharged once for all, by the believer's
>    penal death in the death of Christ; so that he is no longer a "debtor
>    to the flesh to live after the flesh" (Ro 8:12).

**APPENDIX - “The Divine Exchange” and is illustrated in the following texts:**

- 2 Cor 5:21, God made him who had no sin to be sin for us, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God.
- Gal 1:4, who gave himself for our sins to rescue us from the present evil age, according to the will of our God and Father.
- Gal 3:13, Christ redeemed us from the curse of the law by becoming a curse for us. For it is written: “Cursed is everyone who is hung on a tree.
- John 3:16, For God so loved the world that He gave His one and only Son, that everyone who believes in Him shall not perish but have eternal life.
- 2 Cor 8:9, For you know the grace of our Lord Jesus Christ, that though He was rich, yet for your sakes He became poor, so that you through His poverty might become rich.
- 1 Peter 3:18, For Christ also suffered for sins once for all, the righteous for the unrighteous, to bring you to God. He was put to death in the body but made alive in the Spirit,
- Isa 53:4-6, Surely He took on our infirmities and carried our sorrows; yet we considered Him stricken by God, struck down and afflicted.  But He was pierced for our transgressions, He was crushed for our iniquities; the punishment that brought us peace was upon Him, and by His stripes we are healed.  We all, like sheep, have gone astray, each of us has turned to our own way; and the LORD has laid on him the iniquity of us all.

That is, Jesus was treated as we deserve so that we can be treated as He deserved.  This is sometimes expressed another way:  Jesus took responsibility for our sin!